# Want to stop build for a particular working set in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I have a number of working sets, such as APPLICATION, MODULE, UI, and more. When I clean and build my project in Eclipse, I am getting errors related to the UI working set (there are Java projects inside the UI working set).

How can I keep Eclipse from building the UI working set?

Comment: What is it you are actually asking for?

Comment: When i clean and build eclipse i am getting errors in UI working set(There are java projects inside UI working set )  I just don't want UI should be build

Comment: Can you [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/1005844/edit) your question with that information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to eclipse File->new->Other->Faceted Project->Give project name
and add it to UI working set

Eclipse will not build that working set